# Unable to create a Spy on a constructor in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, spock-spy

The declaration I'm looking to create a spy on:

```
 Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(producerProps)
```

My attempts to create the spy failed:

```
 def spySvc = GroovySpy(service, global:true)
    2 * new service.createKafkaProducer() >> mockedProducer; // fail
    2 * new KafkaProducer(_) >> mockedProducer;   // fail
    2 * new KafkaProducer<String,String>(_) >> mockedProducer; //fail
```

But when I factor out the Producer creation into its own method createKafkaProducer() and create a spy on the method invocation like so , it works:

```
 2 * service.createKafkaProducer() >> mockedProducer; // success
```

Any ideas?

( I realize that the code should be refactored to use proper DI, then the problem is trivial and doesn't need a Spy )

Comment: "..._then the problem is trivial and doesn't need a Spy_" -- So you want it to be difficult?

Comment: I want to understand how spies work better , why they work when instantiation is in a function and don't work when in line. I'll go over the source code over the weekend , maybe I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: Maybe your class must be a groovy class or at least have a Groovy MOP (Meta Object Protocol). See https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/81

Comment: I think @rafaelim is correct , KafkaProducer is a statically compiled code and GroovySpies don't work on it

Answer (score 0):

I think @rafaelim is correct , KafkaProducer is a statically compiled code and GroovySpies don't work on it .